# Rectangles instead of text in Dart Editor

Tags: dart, dart-editor

yesterday I updated my Dart Editor to the newest version (25719). When I opened my code in it, some pieces changed into rectangles. I made a screenshot of this [problem](https://twitter.com/janveselynet/status/363988056849653761/photo/1).

I tried to downgrade to version 24898 of Dart that I used before (and everything was all right), but this not helped, rectangles remained.

Has anyone same problem? Some ideas why this problem appeared?

Thanks for your responses.

Comment: It appears to be a font problem (not every character you want to display is available in this particular font), *except* for the fact that I presume the missing statements wouldn't make sense in "all weird characters". Can you (a) show what one of the missing texts is, and (b) attempt to change font used?

Comment: There is another option: Bad Syntax Highlighting. Try this as an experiment: put double quotes around one of the box strings. That will make the editor think it's a plain string. Does the text re-appear?

Comment: Hey, thanks for you help! When I tried experiment with quotes, text re-appeared. Than I tried to change font to another and rectangles disappeares. So it is font problem probably. Thank you...:)